# How to get the union of the two 3D matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have two 3D matrix A and B. The size of A and B are both 40*40*20 double.
The values in matrix A and B are either 0 or 1. The number of "1" in A are 100,
the number of "1" in B are 50. The "1" in matrix A and B may or may not be in 
the same coordinates. I want to get the union of matrix A and B, called C. The values in 3D matrix C is either "1" or "0".  The number of "1" in C is less than or equal to 150. My question is how to get the 3D matrix C in Matlab?

Comment: Is `C = A | B` what you want?

Comment: @LuisMendo, is it simple like this?

Comment: Luis has it. Write it as an answer.

Comment: @angelababy - Yes it is that simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the operator [or](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/or.html), which is a `logical or`. So `or(a,b)` is equivalent to the logical operation `a | b`.

```
C = or(A,B);
C = a | b;
```

`|` and `or` are the same operator in MatLab, it's just two different way to call it.

I think this is the best solution as long as it's integrated into MatLab. However, you have plenty different ways to do it.

Just as an example, you can do

```
C = logical(a+b);
```

`logical` is an operator that convert every value into logical values. Long story short, it will replace any value different of `0` by `1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can approach it in 2 ways. The more efficient one is using vectors but you can also do it in classical nested for loops.

```
A = rand(40,40,20);
A = A > 0.01; # Get approximate 320 ones and rest zeros
B = rand(40,40,20);
B = B > 0.005; # Get approximate 160 ones and rest zeros
C = zeros(size(A));
for iter1 = 1:size(A,1)
    for iter2 = 1:size(A,2)
        for iter3 = 1:size(A,3)
            C(iter1,iter2,iter3) = A(iter1,iter2,iter3)|B(iter1,iter2,iter3)
        end
    end
end
```

This method will be very slow. You can vectorized it to improve performance

```
C = A|B
```